# Do not allow commit when files are in unmerged state

Tags: git, merge

Git allows you to commit even when there are files in unmerged state, when i use

```
git commit -a -m "message"
```

I know is it valid but is there any way to stop the user from using commit -a option after merge

Thanks
Ankita Nema

Answer (score 2):

I would start at the root of the problem and examine why there are unstaged changes when you do a merge.

As a rule of thumb, either [stash away](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your changes before doing a pull, or [commit](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) them so that your repository is clean for the incoming merge.

Sample:

Suppose you are working on something and don't want to commit right now since you aren't done. But you need to merge something in that's important to your task.

```
git stash save "description"
git pull
# merge everything and commit merge changes
git stash pop   #brings back all your changes from before
```

Git will then re-apply everything you saved with git stash save and you are ontop of a merged repository with your uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "pre-commit" hook.

In your ".git/hooks" directory, create an executable file called pre-commit.

This program is triggered each time a commit is done on your repository : if the return code is not 0, the commit is aborted.

In this program, you can check the files to be commited for the "<<<<<<<…" chain. If you find it, it is a clue that there are still unmerge files: so you refuse the commit (with an explicit error message).

You will find in the ".git/hooks" directory a "pre-commit.sample" file showing you how pre-commit works. You will just have to adapt it (a simple "grep" should be fine).

Comment: Good idea, do you have an example script?